# how can copy a database to an other use mssql managment studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one machine only (A) and I have a databese (db1) and I want to copy this database to same machine but to a newone database db2.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and my database is MS SQL Server 2008

How can do that

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Manoj I try the solution 3 BUT first I deleted the destination databse (db2)
and then made the restore and works fine.

So the solution is
A. Delete Destination database
B. See @Manoj Solution 3

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1.**

You can use export database feature.

- Right-click your database in Object Explorer.
- Click Tasks
- Click Export Data

After this you can select source and destination.

However this will "copy" only data, stored procedures will be not copied.

**Solution 2.**

You can generate SQL scripts to re-create all objects in database (including stored procedures).

- Right-click your database in Object Explorer.
- Click Tasks
- Click Generate Scripts

However I dont know if this will copy all objects with data in tables or just table structure.

**Solution 3.**

Edited.

Use backup/restore feature.

For details see [Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2307290/manoj) answer above/below.

Comment: Why would you do that rather than `Backup and Restore`?

Comment: @t3hn00b I was editing and adding info about Backup/restore when you wrote that :)

Comment: I think back up is not required when its in a same machine. You can directly restore with a new database name.

Comment: @Manoj that depends on the SQL version. Express doesn't support it.

Comment: Yes it is. Its supported by express version too.

Comment: @Ambitos try solution 3 then. It should preserve keys and everything else.

Comment: I try this but take an error message like this Thank you for yor replace. I try but I have an error message "TITLE: Restore failed for Server 'LAPTOP-2\SQLEXPRESS'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SigmaActivationService.mdf' cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'SigmaActivationService'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) " SigmaActivationService is my original database db1

Answer (score 1):

try this way when it has to be in same machine

```
1. RightClick on you existing database  then - Task - Restore - Database 
2. A new window will open
3. Specify new database name in "To Database"
4. Then click OK
```

Thanks

Manoj

Comment: Thank you for yor replace. I try but I have an error message "TITLE: Restore failed for Server 'LAPTOP-2\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SigmaActivationService.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'SigmaActivationService'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
" SigmaActivationService is my original database db1